AWS API Gateway Lambda Authorizer Returning 403 Error Despite Allow Policy
I am using a Lambda authorizer with AWS API Gateway and I am encountering a 403 error, even though my Lambda authorizer returns an Allow policy.
I examined the Lambda authorizer function to ensure that it correctly processes the incoming request, decodes the JWT token, and generates an appropriate policy document. Specifically, I checked that the function returns an Allow effect for the required resource and that the resource ARN matches the request's method and path.
export const handler = async function (event: any, callback: Callback, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayAuthorizerResult> {
  try {
    logger.info('Event: ', event);
    const permissions = await getUserIdFromEvent(event);
    console.log('Permissions: ', permissions);

    if (isAuthorized(event, permissions)) {
      return {
        principalId: '73947882-6071-70a1-f3ea-4b043e61740f',
        policyDocument: {
          Version: '2012-10-17',
          Statement: [
            {
              Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
              Effect: 'Allow',
              Resource: event.methodArn,
            },
          ],
        }
      } as AuthResponse;
    } else {
      return {
        principalId: '73947882-6071-70a1-f3ea-4b043e61740f',
        policyDocument: {
          Version: '2012-10-17',
          Statement: [
            {
              Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
              Effect: 'Allow',
              Resource: event.methodArn,
            },
          ],
        }
      } as AuthResponse;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      principalId: '73947882-6071-70a1-f3ea-4b043e61740f',
      policyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
          {
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Resource: event.methodArn,
          },
        ],
      }
    } as AuthResponse;
  }
};

I examined the Lambda authorizer function to ensure that it correctly processes the incoming request, decodes the JWT token, and generates an appropriate policy document. Specifically, I checked that the function returns an Allow effect for the required resource and that the resource ARN matches the request's method and path.

Can you provide information about how the lambda is connected to API Gateway, please?

I created a lambda authorizer on the API gateway. When I press the Test button, I see that it has created an Allow policy. But I still get 403

In general, the lambda code looks fairly good, I shared some recommendations below (see "Lambda code").
I can't tell whether the connection between the API Gateway and the Lambda is correct (asked to share this on a comment). But I'll indicate how this can be done.
On API Gateway, go to the endpoint definition (under Resources), you should see Method request. Under its settings, Authorization should have a token authorizer linked to your lambda.
To setup a token authorizer, in the API's menu choose Authorizers, create a new one of type Lambda (more details on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html).
Once you share more information we might be able to help you pinpoint the issue and respective solution.
Lambda code
The principalId should be the user's sub, so usually the decoded JWT's sub.
I see you have the event.methodArn as the statement's resource. You could use * there to help with testing (then, once you have it working, you could iteratively close access to the requested method).
Note: I'm assuming the code you shared was for testing purposes only (all requests are being allowed to go through), but the code of you lambda should return "Deny" on situations where the user should not be authenticated. I would have an "if user can be authenticated, allow them", then a "catch-all" return at the end (outside of the try/catch) returning "Deny".
Additional Tips
To help debugging the request being processed, you can enable API Gateway's Execution Logs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html).
It's super useful, it indicates each step of the request processing:

the request received by the API GW
whether it required an API Key or not (and whether it had remaining requests in the usage plan's quota)
the request that was forwarded to the authorization lambda
the response of the auth lambda
the request sent to the server (if the endpoint is a proxy one)
the response from the server
the response sent to the client

On API Gateway:

Select the API
Select the stage
Under "Logs and tracing", click on "edit"
Select the desired level of settings and what to log

Note: this is not recommended to be enabled in production environments - see ps://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html.

Thank you for the valuable information, but I did everything you said but it still didn't work. I test it in the Authorizer test section, it says Allow, but I still get 403.
